# Android app freezing when user clear memory

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, gps

I'm developing an application that basically uses Google Maps V2 to periodically receive the phone's location and communicate with the Web API, and Firebase for notifications. But the phone crashes completely whenever the application remains active for a long time (approximately one hour or more) and the user tries to clear the device memory.

Any hint or suggestion of what might be causing this problem?
(If they need to see any files I'll post)

EDIT- I'm having the following error on console:
Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation

Comment: the stacktrace would help, please add that to the question and relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You app have memory memory leakage. Hope these tow links will help:

[Investigating Your RAM Usage](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html)

[Memory leaks in Android — identify, treat and avoid](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8#.k5t5zugu4)

Comment: I has check the Memory usage, and I think is not this the reason of problem. The app use around 30mb of memory.